# Specific xml child based on combobox selected item

Tags: c#, xml, children

This may be a duplicate, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

I have a ComboBox that is populated from an xml file. When I select an item in the ComboBox I want to populate a listBox with the "Special" elements from that same xml file.

xml:

```
 <ClassID Barbarian="Barbarian">
    <Name>Barbarian</Name>
    <Alignment>NG CG NN CN NE CE</Alignment>
    <Special>Fast Movement</Special>
    <Special>Rage Power</Special>
 </ClassID>
```

I can get the listBox to populate with ALL the "Special" elements, but I only want the ones for the specified class name (i.e. Barbarian attribute).

Code to populate listBox with ALL the "Special" elements, regardless of what ComboBox item is selected:

```
//Gets Specials from xml
public static List<string> GetSpecialsFromXml(string filename, string tagname)
{
    List<string> Specials = new List<string>();
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    
    doc.Load(filename);
   
    XmlNodeList specials = doc.GetElementsByTagName(tagname);

    foreach(XmlNode special in specials)
    {
        Specials.Add(special.InnerText);
    }
    return Specials;
}

//Loads feats into feat list
public void LoadFeats()
{
    List<string> Special = GetSpecialsFromXml(Gamepath, "Special");
    FeatBox.Items.AddRange(Special.ToArray());
}
```

LoadFeats is called with the ComboBox SelectedItemChanged event.

I am still a noob when working with xml files.

Edit: TL;DR solution:

Changed `public static List<string> GetSpecialsFromXml(string filename, string tagname)` to `public List<string> GetSpecialsFromXml(string filename, string tagname)`.

Added `string Combo = ComboBox.Text;` and `string strXPath = $"ClassID[{Combo}='{Combo}']/Special"`

Replaced `XmlNodeList specials = doc.GetElementsByTagName(tagname);`
with `XmlNodeList specials = doc.SelectNodes( strXPath );`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov My bad....like I said, I'm still a noob. I'll fix the terminology. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looking for "tagname", with doc.GetElemnetByTagName, use XPath in a SelectNodes()  function call.  XPath is to XML what SQL is to a database, and is very powerful.

Use an XPath statement like in a "SelectNodes()" call

```
string strXPath= "//ClassID[@Barbarian='Barbarian']/Special"
```

Replace your XmlNodeList specials = doc.GetElementsByTagName(tagname); with this

```
XmlNodeList specials = doc.SelectNodes( strXPath );
```

Then iterate away like you're already doing.

Good Luck with your project

Comment: That looks promising. However, I would need to set strXpath to ComboBox.SelectedItem right? So far its giving an "Object Reference" error when I try to use it. It seems that the ClassID is using a parameter correct? How would I set the parameter to the ComboBox.SelectedItem? Especially if it's giving an Object Reference error? Thanks!

Comment: I had to remove "static" from `public static List<string> GetSpecialsFromXml(string filename, string tagname)` and now I can reference the combobox. Now to get that value into "strXpath".

Comment: Was able to add in the ComboBox.Text using `string Combo = ComboBox.Text;` and `$"ClassID[{Combo}='{Combo}']/Special";`

Comment: Great! You got it.  XPath will serve you well for this any many other situations.